# Find bar plot using composite key

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have a table like below:

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [a12,a12,b11,b113,c13,c13], 
                   'A': [np.nan,np.nan,3,3,np.nan,np.nan],'B':[7,7,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],'C':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,4,4],'D':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})```
````

[Dataframe][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsmCp.png

I wanted to have a box plot using unique values so I did this:

````
dic = df.nunique() # Will get distinct counts of each column
```dic = dic[1:].to_dict()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(dic.keys(),dic.values());
````

But this would be wrong as the unique values of those individual A,B,C and D columns can be repeated in some other rows.

So, is it possible to have a composite key of id and the individual columns and get the box plot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `melt` the dataframe and `drop_duplicates()` and then `groupby` `size` from there:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a12','a12','b11','b113','c13','c13'], 
                   'A': [np.nan,np.nan,3,3,np.nan,np.nan],'B':[7,7,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],'C':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,4,4],'D':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
df1 = (df.melt(id_vars='id')
       .drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'value'])
       .dropna()
       .groupby('variable', as_index=False)
       .size())
plt.bar(df1['variable'], df1['size'])
```

[image]

Comment: It gives the same result. I am trying to make the unique row based on A & id, B &id, C&id, D & id.